# Google Tag Manager - Fire a tag if a cookie exists on the page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a variable in GTM, let's call it "Cookie - Test" of type 1st party cookie. I need a trigger for when this cookie exists on the page. So, if the cookie exists, a tag should fire under this condition.
How could I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You create a GTM variable, that reads your cookie.
Then you create a trigger which fires only, when your variable is not undefined.

The only thing you need to think about is the event your trigger fires on - is it on page load, on a certain dataLayer event and so on.
In case the event doesn't matter, you can create a custom event trigger, enter ".*" as event name and select the matches regex checkbox. If done so, it fires on every event as long as the cookie is defined. For this solution, you should usually select firing "once per page" in your tag settings, otherwise your tag will fire quite a lot of times.